# How to calculate specific latent heat from statistical mechanics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

In statistical mechanics, we can compute specific heat capacity $C$ from the Hamiltonian $H$. How about specific latent heat $L$? It seems the undergraduate courses or even graduated courses did not touch on this topic. In the topic of phase transition, we only discuss critical exponents, but none in specific latent heat.